# msal angular got ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'id_token'

Tags: azure-ad-msal

when I used angular 5.2.11 with @azure/msal-angular 0.1.1, I got the following error message after I completed the login process and back to one of my route.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'id_token'

there are a few posts to say adding `<base href="/">` which I did, but still not help.

the following is my package.json. the whole project was created from vs2017 (15.8.2)->angular template.

```
    {
  "name": "WebApplication1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.11",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^0.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.117",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this by putting below code in the app.routing.ts file

```
{
  path: 'id_token',
  redirectTo: 'path-you-want-to-redirect-to',
},
```

Also, if you want to have another workaround, you can use the below code in your app.component.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationStart)
    .subscribe((data: NavigationStart) => {
      if (data.url === '/id_token') {
        this.hash = window.location.hash;
        this.router.navigate(['path-you-want-to-navigate-to']);
      }
    });
}
```

I would suggest going with adding the route in the routing.ts file.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming here lately, this is updated for newer rxjs version
(Code goes in app.component.ts)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(filter ((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationStart) ).subscribe( (data: NavigationStart) => {
          if (data.url === '/id_token') {
            let hash = window.location.hash;
            console.log("hash is : " + hash);
    
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
          }
        });
}
```